# The value of id is always "0" Laravel on cpanel

Tags: laravel

Good Day 
I have a Laravel 7 project that's having some issues, first i have this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNfp2.png)

The solution that i found for that error is to edit 'strict' value to false in `config/database.php`. This fixed the error. But now i just realized that every time I create a user the value of the id is always "0" [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idHhP.png)

Here is my migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('phone_number');
        $table->string('client_address');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because of your `id` field in table is not **AuthoIncrement**
first of all remove `users` table in database
then remove `create_users_table` record in `migrations` table in database
and then change your migration to this

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

and then `php artisan migrate`

Comment: how do i run php artisan migrate on cpanel?

Comment: @jamesrusselbonos Use the Terminal (located under the Advanced tab in cPanel), or you can SSH into your server. You need to `cd` into your project in the Terminal, then run the `php artisan migrate` command